# What does ~/Library/Application\ Support/Knowledge/ folder do?

Tags: macos

After upgrading to MacOS Sierra, a new folder `~/Library/Application\ Support/Knowledge/` emerged, I'm not sure what it stores

I already tried to google for it, but only got results for `Application Support` folder.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

#### knowledge-agent

`/usr/libexec/knowledge-agent` writes its databases to
`~/Library/Application Support/Knowledge` and `/var/db/CoreDuet/Knowledge`.

This is Siri's proactive knowledge functionality. Siri will read data from the services you enable in System Preferences → Siri → Siri Suggestions & Privacy, writing data it finds useful into the database.

[image]

Comment: On 10.13 I have the so called Siri de-activated at every junture possible, but after I tried Apple Notes and then decided not to use it, knowledge-agent requests appeared. Until grg supplied this answer I did not make the connection. Sure enough I checked that box and of course 'Apple' had automatically added Notes to the Siri learn pool, and requests were made even though Notes is totally empty, signed out of, not checked in iCloud, etc... This is even when Siri is, as far as I know, completely blocked.

Comment: Does it have any bad effects to delete the `Knowledge` folder?

Comment: I have Siri disabled there, yet the knowledge-agent was using more CPU than any other app. How is that possible?