# knowledgeC.db could not be backed up

Tags: macbook-pro, backup, time-machine, monterey

My Time Machine backups keep failing.

I get the message

> Time Machine couldn't complete the backup to "NAS server"

> "/private/var/db/CoreDuet/Knowledge/knowledgeC.db" could not be backed up.

[image: /private/var/db/CoreDuet/Knowledge/knowledgeC.db]

The issue started a couple of days ago, but now it recurs regularly.

Rebooting does not help. Running `First Aid` in `Disk Utility` shows no problems.

The file in question seems to be [used by Siri](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/313742/what-does-library-application-support-knowledge-folder-do) to [track app usage](https://www.mac4n6.com/blog/2018/8/5/knowledge-is-power-using-the-knowledgecdb-database-on-macos-and-ios-to-determine-precise-user-and-application-usage), but disabling Siri does not help. It appears [I am not alone in having this problem](https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/94tauq/knowledgecdb/), but I haven't been able to find any solution. Is there one? Would deleting the `Knowledge` folder have any adverse effects?

I'm running macOS Monterey 12.1 on a MacBook Pro 2021 (M1).

The `Knowledge` folder seems remarkably inaccessible:

```sh
> sudo bash
# pwd
/private/var/db/CoreDuet
# ls
Knowledge       People
# ls -l
ls: Knowledge: Operation not permitted
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  7 root  wheel  224 Dec  2 07:07 People
# cd Knowledge
cd: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: Operation not permitted
# pwd
/private/var/db/CoreDuet/Knowledge
# ls
ls: .: Operation not permitted
# ls -l
ls: .: Operation not permitted
#
```

However, I can reproduce the same commands on a Mac mini 2020 (M1), so this interaction does seem to be standard behavior for this file and not due to corruption.

@cmason has a promising suggestion, but I am not able to exclude the folder, because it is, as usual, behaving strangely:

```sh
❯ tmutil isexcluded /private/var/db/CoreDuet
[Included]    /System/Volumes/Data/private/var/db/CoreDuet
❯ tmutil isexcluded /private/var/db/CoreDuet/Knowledge
tmutil: isexcluded requires Full Disk Access privileges.
To allow this operation, select Full Disk Access in the Privacy
tab of the Security & Privacy preference pane, and add Terminal
to the list of applications which are allowed Full Disk Access.
❯ tmutil addexclusion /private/var/db/CoreDuet/Knowledge
/private/var/db/CoreDuet/Knowledge: Error (-50) while attempting to change exclusion setting.
```

Note that the terminal that I am running these command in, most definitely *has* `Full Disk Access`.

Howerver, I did succeed in excluding the entire `/private/var/db/CoreDuet/` folder. I'll wait and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: Can you find a reason in the Console.app?

Comment: @krema I have tried and failed. Unfortunately, I don't find the Console.app easy to navigate. Using the search field gives me nothing. Any tips on where I should look?

Comment: If you disabled Siri, did you delete that file?

Comment: @SolarMike I did not. I disabled Siri using the Preferences. Is it safe to delete the file? I don’t want to end up with a corrupted OS.

Comment: Having this problem on Ventura 13.1 beta (22C5050e), for the folder `~/Library/Application Support/Knowledge` -- can't back up the infamous `knowledgeC.db` which is 22.5 MB.  I can view the folder and stuff without any problems, from a regular shell, and also was able to `tmutil addexclusion` it (again, without complaint).  Crossing fingers ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Time Machine generally does not backup system logs or generally any temporal-based information. Generally, knowledgedc.db is a iOS SQLite db that effectively is a logfile on iOS. (I suspect this might be used on Monterey to support UIKit/iOS apps, but can not confirm). Therefore it is likely being excluded by Time Machine.

You can confirm this on your machine by using the `isexcluded` command. Try `tmutil isexcluded /private/var/db/CoreDuet/Knowledge`

If it is, you can try to `addexclusion`. See the tmutil Man page.

Time Machine generally excludes:

- System log files
- Spotlight indexes
- Cache files
- Trash
- Files excluded by applications

Comment: Interesting suggestion. I've amended my question with my attempts to do this.

Comment: Yes! `tmutil addexclusion /private/var/db/CoreDuet/` fixed it for me!

Comment: Glad the workaround helped.  But you may still have an underlying issue (important or not I don't know) as TM should successfully backup the knowledge database.

Comment: @Gilby the issue is that knowledgeC.db is actually a log file, thus the exclusion

Comment: I know the content contains past activity, but it is a database, not a log file. It is not excluded by default.  It is included in my TM backup and would be restored if I needed it.  I am sure that your answer is a workaround, but it does not address the underlying issue (which @KlasMellbourn may not be bothered about).

Comment: @Gilby I am absolutely open to a better solution. Please post one if there is one. The award has not been granted yet, even though this is the best answer so far.

Comment: You should start with `sudo ls -lae@O /private/var/db/CoreDuet/Knowledge` and compare with a Mac where the backup is working to see if there anything different on yours. But that is another question. I see (from posts elsewhere) you have already discovered some of Sarah Edwards' presentations on the use and abuse of macOS/iOS databases - lots of useful (and worrying) info.