# What is `knowledgeconstructiond` doing?

Tags: daemons, ventura

Just installed Ventura on a 2017 macbook pro 15", and for the last 10 minutes or so a daemon called `knowledgeconstructiond` has been using sizeable but not problematic amounts of CPU. Was curious what it was (intriguing name) and didn't get far with a google search (found this: https://keith.github.io/xcode-man-pages/knowledgeconstructiond.8.html). What is `knowledgeconstructiond` doing?

Comment: This is also pretty vague: https://keith.github.io/xcode-man-pages/intelligenceplatformd.8.html

Comment: Interesting question. `man knowledgeconstructiond` suggests it is building knowledge about your computer and how you use it. Databases it uses are in `~/Library/IntelligencePlatform`. Start by having a look in them.

Comment: On my Mac `~/Library/IntelligencePlatform` is pretty well empty of content. So it has not done anything much for me. Maybe different for you. Speculation: might depend on how much Siri 'intelligence' you have turned on.

Comment: `IntelligencePlatform` is new, but I assume is related to `~/Library/Application Support/Knowledge` which has been around for many years. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/313742/what-does-library-application-support-knowledge-folder-do with its rather vague answer. Also: http://www.mac4n6.com/blog/2018/8/5/knowledge-is-power-using-the-knowledgecdb-database-on-macos-and-ios-to-determine-precise-user-and-application-usage